# Can something be done to these illegible info in the graduated version of the site?

Tags: feature-request, design

I noticed that on the first page of the main site, the time and the reputation scores next to the user names are displayed in grey color making them a bit illegible.

Here is a screenshot highlighting the issue:

[image: screenshot]

Would it not be better if they were in some other color making them more prominent?

Comment: I'm looking at the site now and it's not entirely clear to me what point you are talking about. I don't see any "time" display, and the reputation number next to the user name seems pretty usable to me. Perhaps a screen shot of the bit you think is problematic would make this easier to identify and perhaps agree with?

Comment: @Caleb Attached a screen shot now.

Comment: That's better. I see what you're saying now. I kind of like the focus being taken off those numbers and put onto the darker titles and question summary text, but perhaps it is a shade too light...

Comment: @Caleb Even the 'time' that is displayed after each comment is also not very clearly visible. Visibility of these texts could be improved yet the contrast may be maintained between the different texts to keep the relevant texts in focus

Answer (score 0):

While only the site devs can change the default color scheme, there are browser extensions that users can install to change how webpages appear on their local machines. For example, while I like the visual theme here overall, I use a Firefox extension called Stylish to increase the contrast between the colors for the visited- and not-visited question links on the main page.

I can put together a file in a minute or so that would change the colors of the text items you mentioned in your question and upload it to the Stylish site, where you could download and run it without too much trouble.

Stylish is available for Firefox ([*here*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)) and Chrome ([*here*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)).

Again, it only changes the appearance on the local machine. The Stack Exchange devs are the ones who could adjust the default color scheme.

Let me know if I can upload that file for you. Ciao.